# Error with maven. No error with the same external library

Tags: java, maven, spring-tool-suite, spire.xls

I'm trying to use the spire.office.free library to manage office files from java. For this I have a project using spring tool suite with maven for the download of that library. The problem is that when I run the code I get the following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.spire.office.packages.sprkzh (in unnamed module @0x29647f75) cannot access class sun.security.action.GetPropertyAction (in module java.base) because module java.base does not export sun.security.action to unnamed module @0x29647f75
at com.spire.office.packages.sprkzh.spr??(Unknown Source)
at com.spire.office.packages.sprkzh.spr??(Unknown Source)
at com.spire.office.packages.sprkzh.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.spire.office.packages.sprfqg.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.spire.office.packages.sprhqg.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.spire.xls.core.spreadsheet.XlsWorkbook.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.spire.xls.Workbook.<init>(Unknown Source)
at Eu.Extrae.Principal.main(Principal.java:21)
```

At this moment java console informs me that it is not able to access the code of the library

Class file editor

The curious thing about the matter is that if I download the spire.office.free and use it as an external library the problem disappears and everything works correctly.
I know that is a solution to the problem but I prefer to use maven in any case

Any solution?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You muss download and add Jar file. I have this problem with excel, and I added the jar build path/configure build pat/maven dependencies and add the downloaded jar and problem solved

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).